# Hola, tengo una duda sobre un grafico sobre R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Les adjunto una foto del resumen de mi base de datos.
Lo que quiero hacer es ver si Existen claras diferencias entre MBA y estudiantes de pregrado, o entre hombres y mujeres, respecto de sus preferencias por atributos y marcas de autos.
Para esto realice el siguiente comando:

```
estudios.cars <- cars %>%
  group_by(MBA,Gender,Choice)%>%
  summarize(Size = n(),
            RelativeSize = percent(n()/nrow(cars)),
            Trendy = mean(cars$Trendy),
            Styling = mean(cars$Styling),
            Reliability = mean(cars$Reliability),
            Sportiness = mean(cars$Sportiness),
            Performance = mean(cars$Performance),
            Comfort = mean(cars$Comfort))
```

Mi problema es que quiero graficar todo eso con ggplot y no he logrado hacerlo, ojala puedan ayudarme gracias :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ¿graficar puntualmente que dato? ¿Qué tipo de gráfico? tratas de hacer más concreta la pregunta asi podremos ayudarte. Suerte.